# How to disable location services for an iphone Simulator app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there a way to disable/enable location services on iPhone simulator through objective c code?

[image: screenShot]

I have read other questions already, but they mostly seem to talk about core location services. Is there something to handle this? (I also would not mind using undocumented API if any exist)

Comment: Do you want to test what happens when it gets turned off or do you want to turn it on?

Comment: Well, i just want it turned off. Is there any way to do this through code?

Comment: N/M my comment, I get what you are saying now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your code can not enable or disable the users Location Services.  Nor should it be able to.  You don't want Apps with the ability to make that decision for the user.

Comment: But i do want the App to make that decision for the user. This app wont be on the app store.

Comment: But you don't want other people to make that decision for you.  If you are allowed to make an app that changes the settings then everyone is allowed to make an app that changes the settings.

Comment: Ok. I understand that it can't be done through code. But this App is for personal use only and never to be released on the app store. I understand your concern though.